# Using AJAX in a rails app to update a model field without using a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

Each row is from this partial:

```
<div class="row chord-table-row" id= <%= "chord-#{chord.id}" %>>
    <div class="small-1 columns"><%= chord.id %></div>
    <div class="small-2 columns"><%= chord.name %></div>
    <div class="small-3 columns"><%= chord.description %></div>
    <div class="small-3 columns"><%= chord.user.username %></div>
    <div class="small-3 columns"><%= link_to 'Approve', approve_path, class: 'chord-approval-button' %></div>
</div>
```

How can I make the 'Approve' button go to the `approve` action in the `chords_controller`, which will update the `state` field of the Chord, and then run the JS/Coffeescript in `approve.js.coffee`?

I would (ideally) like to use `remote: true` in the 'Approve' link, but I am not sure how to ensure that the controller knows which Chord is being approved.

Right now the #approve action looks like this:

```
def approve
  chord.approve
  # this method is on the Chord model and is working
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

I'd like to do this in the right "rails" way, so any guidance/advice would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a member route for approval:

```
resources :chords do
  member do
    post 'approve'
  end
end
```

Then the url helper will accept chord / chord id. You can use `remote: true` just like you want to:

```
<%= link_to 'Approve', approve_chord_path(chord), remote: true, method: :post %>
```

Chord id will arrive in params as `params[:id]` so you can do this in your controller:

```
@chord = Chord.find(params[:id])
@chord.approve
```

Your `respond_to` block looks good and your JavaScript will run.

Comment: Perfect, I've been searching for something like this for ages. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

view:

```
<%= link_to_function 'Approve', "$.get('#{approve_path}', {chord_id: #{chord.id}})", class: 'chord-approval-button' %>
```

approve.js:

```
$('dom#u_need_to_change').html('<%= j render partial: 'partial_you_need_to_render' %>')
```

that is all

of course, you need correct routes (`get`, or you can better change it to `post`, not really matters) and `approve.js` has to be in right place (`views/chords` folder, i guess)